# Best approach to redirect an URL using REST

Tags: java, rest, servlets

Can anyone suggest me which is the best approach to redirect an URL using REST among the below two ways:

```
1. httpResponse.sendRedirect("URL");
2. Response.temporaryRedirect(new URI("path"));
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many forms of redirect. The [`3xx`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection) family of HTTP status codes contains:

- `301 Moved Permanently`
- `307 Temporary Redirect`

These and the other codes have different semantic. Which is right depends on your situation. Have the resources been permanently been moved to a new location? Or is the redirect only temporary?

Answer (score 21):

### There are several types of redirects

According to the [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4), the current reference for the semantics and content of the HTTP/1.1, there are [several types of redirects](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4). They are all

> 1. Redirects that indicate the resource might be available at a
>    different URI, as provided by the Location field, as in the
>    status codes `301` (Moved Permanently), `302` (Found), and `307`
>    (Temporary Redirect).
> 2. Redirection that offers a choice of matching resources, each
>    capable of representing the original request target, as in the
>    `300` (Multiple Choices) status code.
> 3. Redirection to a different resource, identified by the Location
>    field, that can represent an indirect response to the request, as
>    in the `303` (See Other) status code.
> 4. Redirection to a previously cached result, as in the `304` (Not
>    Modified) status code.

The correct one depend on your needs. However, these are the most commons:

> [**6.4.2.  301 Moved Permanently**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.2)
>
> The `301` (Moved Permanently) status code indicates that the target
> resource has been assigned a new permanent URI and any future
> references to this resource ought to use one of the enclosed URIs. [...]

> [**6.4.4.  303 See Other**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.4)
>
> The `303` (See Other) status code indicates that the server is
> redirecting the user agent to a different resource, as indicated by a
> URI in the Location header field, which is intended to provide an
> indirect response to the original request. [...]

> [**6.4.7.  307 Temporary Redirect**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.7)
>
> The `307` (Temporary Redirect) status code indicates that the target
> resource resides temporarily under a different URI and the user agent
> MUST NOT change the request method if it performs an automatic
> redirection to that URI. [...]

### Performing the redirects in JAX-RS

By the code you posted in the question, I believe you are using the [JAX-RS](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxrs-2_0-fr-eval-spec/jsr339-jaxrs-2.0-final-spec.pdf) API. If so, you can perform the redirects as following:

- [**301 Moved Permanently**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.2):

```java
URI uri = ...
return Response.status(Status.MOVED_PERMANENTLY).location(uri).build();
```

- [**303 See Other**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.4) (aka POST/redirect/GET):

```java
URI uri = ...
return Response.seeOther(uri).build();
```

- [**307 Temporary Redirect**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.7):

```java
URI uri = ...
return Response.temporaryRedirect(uri).build();
```

For more details, the [`Response`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html) class documentation may be useful.

### Other details that can be useful when using JAX-RS

You also can inject the [`UriInfo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html) in your REST endpoints:

```java
@Context
UriInfo uriInfo;
```

And get some useful information, such as the [base URI](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html#getBaseUri--) and the [absolute path of the request](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html#getAbsolutePath--). It will be useful when building the URI for redirection.

A resource method with redirection will be like:

```java
@Path("/foo")
public class MyEndpoint {

    @Context
    private UriInfo uriInfo;

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response myMethod() {
        URI uri = uriInfo.getBaseUriBuilder().path("bar").build();
        return Response.temporaryRedirect(uri).build();
    }
}
```